# AngularJS Annotation Questions

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Hi I am new to Angular and JS Frameworks in general.  I was wondering if someone could help me decipher some of the notation.

From the docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

**Inline Array Annotation**

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}]);
```

**$inject Property Annotation**

```
var MyController = function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}

MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'greeter'];

someModule.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

---

For my education the $inject method is preferred as it is more exploded.  I see three steps: 1) define the function, 2) inject dependencies, 3) attach to parent module.

OK so my questions:
Why are "$scope" and "greeter" listed as parameters to the function and then injected with the $inject?  Wouldn't it be one or the other?

*someModule.controller('MyController', MyController);*

Why is MyController listed twice once as a literal? Is this a type and token thing?  Could it just as easily have been:

*someModule.controller('MyInstanceOfMyController', MyController);*

Thanks for any illumination

Answer (score 0):

> For my education the $inject method is preferred as it is more exploded. I see three steps: 1) define the function, 2) inject
>   dependencies, 3) attach to parent module.

I prefer this notation as well, it reads better.

> OK so my questions: Why are "$scope" and "greeter" listed as
>   parameters to the function and then injected with the $inject?
>   Wouldn't it be one or the other?

This makes sense, you are telling the injector what to inject, and the function declaration takes these in as usable parameters.

You could change "greeter2 to "newGreeter" in the injector, and you wouldn't need to update the function code in order to use the new module.

> someModule.controller('MyController', MyController);
>
> Why is MyController listed twice once as a literal? Is this a type and
>   token thing? Could it just as easily have been:
>
> someModule.controller('MyInstanceOfMyController', MyController);

Kind of, here you are telling the module
1) What the controller is called
2) Which function defines the controller

These *can* have the same name, but they don't have to.

Comment: Thanks.  I understood all your answers :)  On that last point "1) What the controller is called".  Would it be correct to say "It is what I want to call the controller within "someModule"?

Comment: "This makes sense, you are telling the injector what to inject, and the function declaration takes these in as usable parameters"


While I understand what your saying I am not sure yet that it makes sense to me.  Passing something into a function as a parameter makes it available within that function....so wtf does "injecting" do? Why both? If "injecting" is like referencing a library, why does it also have to be a parameter?

Comment: Your first comment - yes, that is the name which references it within `someModule`.

Comment: Your second comment - if you just have the libraries as parameters in the function, how would angular know what those libraries actually are? The injector makes code testable by not hard-coding your library references into the controller, that is the point of dependency injection, to make dependencies easy to swap out for testing or replacement.